# public files not found on deployment

Tags: javascript, deployment, web-deployment, netlify, netlify-function

The static files in this [code's](https://github.com/ahmedgaafer/algorithims-visualizer-project) src file

are not found though they work locally just fine.

What am I doing wrong in the deployment?

the deployment [HERE](https://5f5f88850109f4093d51dc66--algorithim-visualizer.netlify.app/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem was that I should have put all the public/ static files in the public folder that netlify sees in the main root